# Are multiplication and division O(1) the way they are implemented on most popularly used computer architectures?

Tags: java, algorithm, cpu-architecture, processor

Are multiplication and division O(1) the way they are implemented on most popularly used computer architectures?

On x86 and ARM for example, are multiplication and division O(1)? What if I use Java's BigInteger class and multiplied or divided two instances of BigInteger? This obviously may not be O(1) but what is the complexity?

Comment: Those are really two different questions.  "the way they are implemented on most popularly used computer architectures" implies hardware instructions with bounded input size, so trivially O(1).  BigInteger addition is almost certainly O(n) for n-digit inputs; BigInteger multiplication as implemented in Java is supposedly O(n^2) for n-digit inputs, but more asymptotically efficient algorithms (e.g. Karatsuba or FFT) are known to exist.

Comment: I understand they are two different questions.

Comment: Why does Java not implement the more asymptotically efficient algorithms?

Comment: It may take very large inputs for the asymptotically optimal algorithms to outperform the O(n^2) solution.  The other algorithms are also much more complex and therefore harder to debug, maintain, and optimize.

Answer (score 3):

`BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` in the Oracle JDK are both O(M*N) for both multiply and divide.

Answer (score 1):

It seems very unlikely that for arbitrary big operands the complexity remains constant. Unless you can have the arbitrary big hardware to follow that (and it would probably not grow linearly).

To answer your question : it vary within different systems and different languages.

However for "normal" sized ints, you can have a look at the ARM docs.

For instance, the [ARM assembly multiply instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihjfeii.html) contains different subsections. Assuming assembly language, and a particular ARM platform, you can dig in the official documentation.
That gives you the number of cycles necessary to perform a multiplication. Because ARM is a RISC machine, it is convenient to have it that way. Then compare that to you vendor chip frequency.

For instance for [ARM7 processors](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0084f/I20211.html).

Also, you may want to have a look at [wikipedia Multiplication_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

It only makes sense to talk about O(f(n)) when n can actually vary over a wide range. The point of big O is we ignore small things and focus on how the run-time scales over a wide range of n.

CPU level multiplication operations are usually constant time nowadays, though in the past some did vary a bit with the size of the arguments. Division may take variable time even today but we are still talking about relatively small and bounded variations. Multiplying fixed size values should be regarded as O(1).

For a bigint library on the other hand I would assume O(n*m) where n and m are the bit lengths of the two operands. This represents the complexity of the most basic and obvious algorithms for multiplication and division.

There are algorithms with better asymptotic complexity than the simple algorithms, but I would want to get confirmation before assuming any particular big-integer library used them.

Unfortunately the documentation for Java's standard big integer library is silent on the issue of computational complexity.

Comment: It's not clearly documented, but in the source for Javas BigInteger you can see that Karatsuba and Toom-3 are implemented, but it stops there and doesn't go on to Schönhage–Strassen.

Comment: Some hardware dividers are faster for smaller inputs, e.g. https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf says that AMD K10's divider was faster for numbers with fewer significant bits in the absolute value of the dividend, according to AMD's optimization manual.  So some large fixed overhead for any division plus an O(log2(dividend)) component.  Or in Pentium M, lower values (for latency and reciprocal throughput) happen for "round" divisors.  (e.g. lots of trailing zeros I guess, or perhaps exactly 1 set bit.  Agner speculates it might be a special-case early-out, not a gradual thing.)

Comment: In Core 2, apparently small quotients are faster.  But reciprocal throughput is in the 12-36 cycle range, so the time function isn't just log2(quotient).  (And the width is limited to 64-bit, so as you say, it's close enough to O(1).)  This is just a selection of older x86 hardware; dividers in modern low-power ARM or RISC-V might be like that, or advances in ALU design might have changed things.  Related: [How sqrt() of GCC works after compiled? Which method of root is used? Newton-Raphson?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54642663) has some info about internals of div/sqrt units.