# How sqrt() of GCC works after compiled? Which method of root is used? Newton-Raphson?

Tags: c, function, math, assembly, sqrt

Just curiosity about the standard `sqrt()` from math.h on GCC works. I coded my own `sqrt()` using Newton-Raphson to do it!

Comment: Why don't you look at the implementation?  GCC is open source.  Note that on many architectures these days, the `sqrt` might be replaced with an explicit CPU instruction that performs the calculation.

Comment: I only see the description of the function on math.h

Comment: yeah, I know fsqrt. But how the CPU does it? I can't debug hardware

Comment: If the square root is calculated at compile time, I believe it's done using the mpfr library. At run time, it's going to depend on your processor and libc implementation. Might be an instruction, might be a function call...

Comment: I think regardless, these libraries are maintained by some of the smartist people that always look for the most optimized solutions. So if the question really being if their implementation is the fastest, answer would be yes...

Comment: The _implementation_ is not in `math.h` -- that's the _interface_.  Look at the source code for GCC.  Regarding your question about `sqrt` on hardware, that's achieved through microinstructions specific to the hardware.  Contact your hardware manufacturer to obtain datasheets if you need to know the algorithm used.

Comment: @paddy, I don't understand that. I'm almost sure the interface has software below, it. NOW, the way your hardware actually achieves those instructions can vary...

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Yes, it does have a software implementation, but because it's a standard library function the compiler can choose to replace it with a similar hardware instruction.  It may even optimize loops to perform multiple calculations in parallel through vectorized instructions (e.g. SIMD)

Answer (score 19):

> yeah, I know fsqrt. But how the CPU does it? I can't debug hardware

Typical div/sqrt hardware in modern CPUs uses a power of 2 radix to calculate multiple result bits at once.  e.g. [http://www.imm.dtu.dk/~alna/pubs/ARITH20.pdf](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/%7Ealna/pubs/ARITH20.pdf) presents details of a design for a Radix-16 div/sqrt ALU, and compares it against the design in Penryn.  (They claim lower latency and less power.)  I looked at the pictures; looks like the general idea is to do something and feed a result back through a multiplier and adder iteratively, basically like long division.  And I think similar to how you'd do bit-at-a-time division in software.

Intel Broadwell introduced a Radix-1024 div/sqrt unit.  [This discussion on RWT](https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=143069&curpostid=143089) asks about changes between Penryn (Radix-16) and Broadwell.  e.g. widening the SIMD vector dividers so 256-bit division was less slow vs. 128-bit, as well as increasing radix.

Maybe also see

- [The integer division algorithm of Intel's x86 processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401194/the-integer-division-algorithm-of-intels-x86-processors) - Merom's Radix-2 and Radix-4 dividers was replaced by Penryn's Radix-16.  (Core2 65nm vs. 45nm).  Also https://specbranch.com/posts/faster-div8/ has some guesswork about how integer `div` might left-justify the bits and use the same hardware as `RCPSS` to get an initial guess, and so on.
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280673/why-does-hardware-division-take-much-longer-than-multiplication
- https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/187/why-is-division-so-much-more-complex-than-other-arithmetic-operations

---

But however the hardware works, **IEEE requires `sqrt` (and mul/div/add/sub) to give a *correctly rounded* result**, i.e. error <= 0.5 ulp, so **you don't need to know how it works, just the performance**.  These operations are special, other functions like `log` and `sin` do *not* have this requirement, and real library implementations usually aren't that accurate.  (And [x87 `fsin` is definitely not that accurate](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/) for inputs near Pi/2 where catastrophic cancellation in range-reduction leads to potentially *huge* relative errors.)

See https://agner.org/optimize/ for x86 instruction tables including throughput and latency for scalar and SIMD `sqrtsd` / `sqrtss` and their wider versions.  I collected up the results in [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125033/floating-point-division-vs-floating-point-multiplication/45899202#45899202)

For non-x86 hardware sqrt, you'd have to look at data published by other vendors, or results from people who have tested it.

Unlike most instructions, `sqrt` performance is typically data-dependent.  (Usually more significant bits or larger magnitude of the result takes longer).

Answer (score 4):

`sqrt` is defined by C, so most likely you have to look in `glibc`.

You did not specify which architecture you are asking for, so I think it's safe to assume x86-64. If that's the case, they are defined in:

- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/e_sqrt.c
- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/e_sqrtf.c
- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/e_sqrtl.c

tl;dr they are simply implemented by calling the x86-64 square root instructions `sqrts{sd}`:

- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sqrtss
- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sqrtsd

Furthermore, and just for the sake of discussion, if you enable fast-math (something you probably should **not** do if you care about result precision), you will see that most compilers will actually inline the call and directly emit the `sqrts{sd}` instructions:

https://godbolt.org/z/Wb4unC

Comment: Compilers can fully inline `sqrt` as long as you use `-fno-math-errno`.  Otherwise GCC inlines it plus a compare&branch to call the library version for NaN inputs, because of the stupid requirement left over from an early C standard that math functions set `errno` on FP errors like negative inputs to sqrt. 
 (Basically on FP invalid exceptions).

Comment: With the full `-ffast-math`, compilers sometimes used to use `rsqrtps` + a Newton iteration to approximate sqrt(x) as `x * approx_recip_sqrt(x)`, although that requires a fixup for non-zero `x`.  And it's not worth doing on modern x86, especially for scalar.  Maybe for vector if it's the only thing you're doing in a loop, otherwise still not.