# Do FP and integer division compete for the same throughput resources on x86 CPUs?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, intel, cpu-architecture

We know that Intel CPUs do integer division and FP div / sqrt on a not-fully-pipelined divide execution unit on port 0.  We know this from [IACA output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021337/what-is-iaca-and-how-do-i-use-it), other published stuff, and experimental testing.  (e.g. https://agner.org/optimize/)

But are there independent dividers for FP and integer (competing only for dispatch via port 0), or **does interleaving two div-throughput-bound workloads make their cost add nearly linearly, if one is integer and the other is FP?**

This is complicated by Intel CPUs (unlike AMD) decoding integer division to multiple uops, e.g. 10 for `div r32` on Skylake.

---

AMD CPUs similarly have their divider on one execution port, but I don't know as much about them and don't have one to test on.  AMD integer division decodes to only a couple uops (to write RDX and RAX), not microcoded.  Experiments on AMD might be easier to interpret without lots of uops flying around being a possible cause for contention between int and fp div.

---

Further reading:

- Semi-related: [Radix divider internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642663/how-sqrt-of-gcc-works-after-compiled-which-method-of-root-is-used-newton-rap)
- [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125033/floating-point-division-vs-floating-point-multiplication/45899202#45899202) - FP div/sqrt vs. multiply/FMA throughputs on various Intel and AMD CPUs.
- [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983453/trial-division-code-runs-2x-faster-as-32-bit-on-windows-than-64-bit-on-linux/52558274#52558274) - Intel's 64-bit integer division is a lot slower.  Decoding to more uops (36 vs. 10 on SKL) and not even saturating the `arith.divider_active` perf counter.

Comment: (spoiler alert: the answer appears to be that FP and integer division *do* compete on Skylake.  Will tidy up my quick test and post it as an answer later.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel CPU architect Ronak Singhal [mentions on Twitter](https://twitter.com/rsinghal1/status/1163230580454019072) that Broadwell (and by implication subsequent architectures until ICL) use the FP hardware for division, but that Ice Lake has a dedicated integer division unit:

> Keep in mind that Broadwell that this was benchmarked on does integer division on the FP divider. In Ice Lake, there is now a dedicated integer divide unit.

So I would expect significant competition. Many of the operations that integer division perform no doubt are plain ALU ops not using the divider, so I wouldn't necessarily expect their inverse throughput to be strictly cumulative but they will definitely compete.

Ronak doesn't imply anything about pre-Broadwell implementation, but based on the similar port assignment and performance going back to at least Sandy Bridge, I think we can expect that the same sharing holds.