# uops for integer DIV instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-architecture

I was looking the Agner Fog's instruction tables [here](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), specifically I was looking at the sandy bridge case, and there is one thing that has caught my attention. If you look DIV instructions you can see that, for example, **r64 DIV instruction can be decoded up to 56 uops! My question is: is it true or have I made a missinterpretation?**

This is something that doesn't even get into my head. I've always thougt that an integer division of 2 registers was decoded in only 1 uop. And thought that that uop was dispatched to Port 0 (for example in Sandy Bridge).

**What I thought that happenned here is: The uop is dispatched to Port0 and it finishes some cycles later. But, thanks to the pipelining, 1 div uop (or another uop that needs port0) can be sent to that port on each cycle. But this has completely broken my schemes: 56 different uops which need to be dispatched in 56 different cycles and occuping 56 ROB entries to ONLY do 1 integer division?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218856/discussion-on-question-by-isma-uops-for-integer-div-instruction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all of those uops run on the actual divider unit on port 0.  It seems only signed `idiv` is that many uops on Skylake, `div r64` is "only" 33 uops.  Perhaps signed `idiv r64` is taking absolute values to do extended-precision division using a narrower HW divider unit, like you'd do for software extended-precision?  ([Why is __int128_t faster than long long on x86-64 GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029428/why-is-int128-t-faster-than-long-long-on-x86-64-gcc/63034921#63034921))

And `idiv`/`div r32` is "only" 10 uops, probably only 1 or 2 of them needing the actual divide unit on port 0, the others doing IDK what on other ports.  Note the counts for `arith.divider_active` shown in Skylake profile results on [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983453/trial-division-code-runs-2x-faster-as-32-bit-on-windows-than-64-bit-on-linux/52558274#52558274) - `div r64` with small inputs barely keeps the actual port 0 divider active for longer than `div r32`, but the other overhead makes it much slower.

FP division is actually single-uop because FP div performance is important in some real-world algorithms.   (Especially effect of one `divpd` on front-end throughput of surrounding code).  See [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125033/floating-point-division-vs-floating-point-multiplication/45899202#45899202)

See also [Do FP and integer division compete for the same throughput resources on x86 CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58422171) - Ice Lake improves the divider HW.

---

See also discussion in comments clearing up other misconceptions.

Related:

- [Why is division more expensive than multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745819/why-is-division-more-expensive-than-multiplication) division is fundamentally hard to pipeline.

I think I've read that modern divider units are typically built with an iterative not-fully-pipelined part, and then 2 Newton Raphson steps which are pipelined.  So that's how division can be partially pipelined on modern CPUs: the next one can start as soon as the current one can move into the Newton-Raphson pipelined part of the execution unit.

Comment: Also related: [Fast hardware integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70132913)