# Why is it quicker to calculate the reciprocal square root than to compute the square root?

Tags: cpu-architecture, sse, numerical-methods, sqrt, square-root

On uops.info VRSQRTPS is listed as having a lower latency than VSQRTPS across all the architectures I've checked. It also has a lower throughput but perhaps there are less units that can do it on most designs.

Intuitively, you would compute the reciprocal square root by finding the square root and then inverting it, so this would be slower than just finding the square root. But this is not what we see.

What makes computing the reciprocal square root faster?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here -- Stack Overflow is strictly scoped to questions one actually faces with answers that will solve a practical problem encountered _while writing code_; "why" questions are unambiguously topical only to the extent that they have answers that are likely to change how one goes about the practice of software development. Perhaps [electronics.se] might be a better fit (as questions with Verilog-centric answers are generally more likely to be on-topic there)?

Comment: Because it's a fast approximation, intended for normalizing geometry vectors like `x*rsqrt(x^2 + y^2)`, especially in games where 12-bit precision might be sufficient without even a Newton iteration.  And perhaps uses the same internal tables as real `sqrtps` uses as a starting point for refining with Newton-Raphson.  Related: [How sqrt() of GCC works after compiled? Which method of root is used? Newton-Raphson?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54642663)

Comment: While it may be contrary to intuition, sqrt is often computed from rsqrt in both hardware and software implementations. The main reason is that there exist efficient *division-free* iterative algorithms for computing rsqrt.

Comment: Do you have a source for that @njuffa ?

Comment: @Sea Erchin I have worked on the implementation of floating-point units for microprocessors and standard math libraries.

Comment: @njuffa do you have something I could read or show other people?

Comment: @Sea Erchin Maybe this can be a useful starting point: [High order algorithms to find square roots and inverses](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/inverse). I have seen and used iterations with quadratic and cubic convergence in practice, i.e. Newton and Halley iterations. Higher-order iterations *may* be used in some arbitrary-precision packages, but I do not have first-hand knowledge of that.